# Login MySQL, PHP y AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con *Phonegap*. Me gustaría que al iniciar sesión, comprobara si existe en la base de datos. En el caso que exista que guarde la dirección del correo electrónico (`email`) en el `localStorage`.

Código *HTML*:

```
<div class="login_container">

    <form id="login-form" method="POST" name="login_form">
        <input class="input_email_login" type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" required>
        <input class="input_password_login" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" required>

        <p>Forgot your password?</p><span>Click here</span>

        <button id="submit_login" type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>

</div>
```

Código *PHP* (alojado en el servidor):

```
<?php
$email = $_POST["email"];
$pas = $_POST["password"];

require_once("../connect.php");

$db = new Conexion();

$dbTable='r_users'; 

$consult = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $dbTable WHERE email=:log AND password=:pas"; 
$result = $db->prepare($consult);
$result->execute(array(":log" => $email, ":pas" => md5($pas)));
$total = $result->fetchColumn();

if($total==1){
    $consult = "SELECT * FROM $dbTable WHERE email=:log AND password=:pas"; 
    $result = $db->prepare($consult);
    $result->execute(array(":log" => $email, ":pas" => md5($pas)));

    if (!$result) { 
        print "<p>Error.</p>\n";
    }else{
        return $email;
        return $pas;
        echo $email;
        echo $pas;
    }
}else{
    return false;
}?>
```

Código *jQuery*:

```
$(function() {
    $('#submit_login').on('click', function() {
        var data_login = $("#login-form").serialize();
        var email = $('.input_email_login').val();
        var password = $(".input_password_login").val();
        $.ajax({
            data: data_login,
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://urlservidor.com/validate_user.php"
        })
        .done(function(){
            alert ("Done " + email + password);
            localStorage.setItem("Email", JSON.stringify(email));
            window.location.replace("../index.html");
        })
        .fail(function(){
            alert ("No");
            window.location.replace("../login.html");
        })
        return false;
    });
});
```

El caso es que al intentar iniciar sesión siempre me da `Done`, me muestra correctamente la dirección del correo electrónico y la contraseña que he introducido. Tanto si el usuario es correcto como si es falso.

Comment: Puede que estés confundiendo el .done() y el .fail(). Tu php siempre vuelve y entra en done() por que la devolucion es vàlida siempre. Checkea devolver correctamente true o false para el done/fail o simplemente pregunta si -.done(data)- data es == a algo que devuelvas de php.

Comment: Muchas gracias.De que manera puedo retornar algun valor del php a el javascript?

Comment: Con echo, pero solo necesitas saber si la consulta es true o false (login ok o no). Por lo cual solo devolveria if(!result) true or false y listo.

Comment: Ya he resuelto el problema, me ha ayudado lo que me has dicho. He dejado una respuesta con la solución por si te interesa. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya he resuelto mi duda. Por si alguien tiene el mismo problema.

**PHP**

```
require_once("../connect.php");

$db = new Conexion();

$dbTable='r_users'; 

$consult = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $dbTable WHERE email=:log AND password=:pas"; 
$result = $db->prepare($consult);
$result->execute(array(":log" => $email, ":pas" => md5($pas)));
$total = $result->fetchColumn();

if($total==1){
    $consult = "SELECT * FROM $dbTable WHERE email=:log AND password=:pas"; 
    $result = $db->prepare($consult);
    $result->execute(array(":log" => $email, ":pas" => md5($pas)));

    if (!$result) { 
        print "<p>Error.</p>\n";
    }else{
        function statustrue(){
            return true;
        }
        statustrue();
        echo json_encode(statustrue());
    }
}else{
    function statusfalse(){
        return false;
    }
    statusfalse();
    echo json_encode(statusfalse());
}   
?>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(function() {
$('#submit_login').on('click', function() {
    var data_login = $("#login-form").serialize();
    var email = $('.input_email_login').val();
    var password = $(".input_password_login").val();
    //localStorage.clear();
    $.ajax({
        data: data_login,
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://urlservidor.com/validate_user.php"
    })
    .done(function(data){
        //alert ("Done " + email + password);
        //alert(data);
        if(data == "true"){
            //alert("true");
            localStorage.setItem("Email", JSON.stringify(email));
            window.location.replace("../index.html");
        } else{
            //alert("false");
            window.location.replace("login.html");
        }
    })
    return false;
});
});
```

Comment: Usas mucho código para la función que éste tiene, tu código puede ser reducido mucho más, y hacerlo mucho más mantenible. Principalmente en tu código PHP

Comment: ¿Cómo podría reducirlo? :S

Comment: Pues ya de por sí solemne sería necesaria hacer una consulta.

Comment: Ya que con una sola consulta puedes saber si hay coincidencia o no, y desde la primera consulta seleccionas todo en vez de solamente hacer un conteo.

Comment: Entonces al seleccionar todo el contenido de tu tabla con *, después puedes hacer un fetchAll(); como esto devuelve un Array puede usar count() y con eso ya sabes si hay coincidencias o no, y en el caso de que las haya ya tienes la información seleccionada!

Answer (score 2):

## AJAX

.fail() es si falla la consulta ajax. Esto quiere decir: errores en php, no existe el archivo (404), error 500, etc.

.done() significa que ha ejecutado el php sin errores.

Tienes los siguientes fallos:

- No estás haciendo un alert de la respuesta, estás haciendo un alert de las variables de javascript que has declarado arriba
- En php estás devolviendo hasta 4 valores a la consulta ajax:

  ```
   }else{
   return $email;
   return $pas;
   echo $email;
   echo $pas;}
  ```

Tienes que devolver sólo un valor, o un objeto para devolver varios valores.

Un ejemplo sencillo de ajax es este:

```
$.ajax({
 method: "POST",
 url: "some.php",
 data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
 .done(function( msg ) {
   alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

Son errores de novato. 
Mírate bien la documentación de AJAX y trastéalo un poco: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: No he pedido que me programen todo el código.

Comment: Quería decir que esos errores que pones son de comenzar con PHP, JQuery y Ajax, que no puedo hacerte todo el código, que es demasiado. Que lo trastées con esas guías que te he puesto!